# How to get rid of pending changes

Tags: teamcity

I have this trigger in my build configuration to trigger this build only when specific files are modified (and skip another not related to production). Build is tested and deployed to production environment. Trigger works correctly.

[image]

But what I am trying to solve are pending changes. Changes committed to VCS that are not triggered for building process and remain in interface.

**Q:** How to get rid these pending changes?

I can run build to remove them but by running build I do a deploy to production server, and I do not want to do this. What's the point of triggers when it is not possible to get rid of pending changes and the build has to be started manually in order to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick explanation of the available toolkit would be beneficial:

### Trigger rules vs. Checkout rules

A VCS Trigger rule is a rule that specifies which particular changes you want to actually start the build. A Pending Change is an indication of which changes were added to **the scope of the entire VCS root** since the last time your build was run. This would, in many cases, indicate the differences between the source code and the latest compiled artifact, as an example.

What your build currently defaults to is that all changes in the VCS are relevant to your build, and that only a (small) subset of these changes should actually trigger a new build. In other words, TeamCity is "keeping an eye on" all of the changes relevant for your build, i.e. the entire VCS root scope.

A Checkout Rule is a rule which *limits the scope* of the VCS root. It specifies two things: a) the *subset* of the VCS contents that you wish to checkout on the agent and b) the *subset* of the VCS contents that you wish is tracked for "Pending changes".

### One option

If you want to *limit the scope of the VCS* for that one particular build, one option is available for you. You could for example create a checkout rule that is similar to your trigger rules, i.e. specifying that you only want to *checkout and track* the paths from your trigger rule, this will then *only* show you "Pending Changes" for changes that match these rules. The downside of this method is that you may not checkout all required files for the job, and may not notice they are missing until your piece of software is deployed to production (what if images are not in `/src/main/**`, or sound files - they won't be included this way, then, unless explicitly included in the checkout rule).

### Another option

...is to simply ignore the "Pending changes" number and list for that one job, if you need all of the VCS content to do a deployment.